# How Blender uses the command line to detect missing texture files

Tags: command-line

How does Blender use the command line to detect missing texture files and display prints? I am not very good at English.

Comment: Do you just want to know whether something is missing or a list of missing files or even fix broken links to the files?

Comment: Yes, missing file list